# Programmatically 301 Redirect

Tags: redirect

How can I programmatically perform a 301 redirect in Magento?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In `Mage_Core_Controller_Response_Http::setRedirect()`, the second option allows you supply the redirect code (defaults to `302`), so

```
Mage::app()->getResponse()
    ->setRedirect($someUrl, 301)
    ->sendResponse();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can throw an exception in the predispatch event:

```
// https://github.com/magento-hackathon/HoneySpam/blob/master/app/code/community/Hackathon/HoneySpam/Model/Observer.php
$e = new Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Exception();
$e->prepareForward('index','error','honeyspam');
throw $e;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to redirect from within a controller, you can use the response object which is on the controller

```
class Some_Controller extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function exampleAction()
    {
        $this->getResponse()->setRedirect('redirect-url.html', 301);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to redirect all URLs that are redirected by Magento with the default code 302 you can create an Observer in your own module for the dispatched event ***controller_response_redirect*** in ***Mage_Core_Controller_Response_Http::setRedirect()***:

```
public function forceDefaultRedirectCode($eventObject)
{
    $urlRedirectionCode = $eventObject->getTransport()->getCode();
    if ($urlRedirectionCode != '302') {
        return;
    }
    $eventObject->getTransport()->setCode(301);
}
```