# Forward Category Page to Product View Page not Working

Tags: magento-1.9, redirect, exception, router

I am trying to *forward* every category page to a product view page using an event observer. But it seems to be not working.

Scenario : I am playing around with Magento router now. As part of this, I am trying to forward every category page in my Magento instance to the product page. The product page which is going to load for a category is the page of first product in that category.

**What I have Tried** : I observed to the event `controller_action_predispatch_catalog_category_view` and added below code to my observer method.

```
public function forwardSingleProCategory(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    //get event data
    $action = $observer->getControllerAction();
    $request = $action->getRequest();

    //get category id
    $categoryId = (int)$request->getParam('id', false);

    //grab category collection
    $layer = Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->setCurrentCategory($categoryId);
    $collection = $layer->getProductCollection();

    //check whether category count is 1. If YES, then do magic
    if ($collection->getSize() > 0) {

        //prepare parameters that needs for the action `catalog/product/view`
        $product = $collection->getFirstItem();
        $actionName = 'view';
        $controllerName = 'product';
        $moduleName = 'catalog';
        $params = array(
            'category' => $categoryId,
            'id'       => $product->getId()
        );

        //tells no to category page router processing further
        $request->setDispatched(false);

        //throw exception with a clear message we need a product page.
        $e = new Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Exception();
        $e->prepareForward($actionName, $controllerName, $moduleName, $params);
        throw $e;

    }

    return $this;
}
```

<sup>See the comments that I have put in the code. If something is not clear in my code please let me know. I can explain</sup>

But I am getting *404 Page* for every category page request. Ooops !!!

**How much I debug** : The 404 page is triggering from `Mage_Catalog_ProductController` itself (which means observer is working fine). The problem lies here in this section :

```
 public function viewAction()
{
    // Get initial data from request
    $categoryId = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('category', false);
    $productId  = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    $specifyOptions = $this->getRequest()->getParam('options');
    ...
    try {
        $viewHelper->prepareAndRender($productId, $this, $params);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        if ($e->getCode() == $viewHelper->ERR_NO_PRODUCT_LOADED) {
            if (isset($_GET['store'])  && !$this->getResponse()->isRedirect()) {
                $this->_redirect('');
            } elseif (!$this->getResponse()->isRedirect()) {
                $this->_forward('noRoute');
            }
        } else {
            Mage::logException($e);
            $this->_forward('noRoute');
        }
    }
```

The problem is `$productId` and `$categoryId` are same (seems that both holds category id value) and hence the line `$viewHelper->prepareAndRender($productId, $this, $params);` is failing and  thus I am getting 404 page.

But in my observer, you can see that I am setting both `category` and `id` parameters via this section

```
$e = new Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Exception();
$e->prepareForward($actionName, $controllerName, $moduleName, $params);
```

I double checked and confirmed that `$params` (holds the right product id for `id` and right category id for `category`) are correct  in my observer.

So my question is how it is get rewriting by category Id in the router process in this scenario ?

How can I make it work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the problem with the above code. I feel this as a bug in Magento. However you can judge my point after going through my answer.

Below is the important part from observer that does the *forward* trick.

```
$product = $collection->getFirstItem();
$actionName = 'view';
$controllerName = 'product';
$moduleName = 'catalog';
$params = array(
    'category' => $categoryId,
    'id'       => $product->getId()
);

//tells no to category page router processing further
$request->setDispatched(false);

//throw exception with a clear message we need a product page.
$e = new Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Exception();
$e->prepareForward($actionName, $controllerName, $moduleName, $params);
throw $e;
```

When we throw an exception `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Exception` after do a proper `prepareForward`, then what will happen is, this will be eventually fire `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::_forward()` method, which you all know do a *forward* in Magento (you can treat a *forward* as a *redirect* with keeping the *URL* same). This `froward()` function will set parameters correctly to the request object. There for `$request` object will have

```
Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Request_Http $request {
    $this->_params = array (
        'category' => 12
        'id'       => 448
    )
}
```

<sup>Here I am assuming *categoryId = 12* and *productId = 448*</sup>

Everything fine upto this. Now router is starting to process the triggered *forward* that we have done right now. **But standard router**<sup>**1**</sup> **while doing *matching*<sup>2</sup> will do an additional rewrite on parameters based on the path information**. This is what make problem in this unique case.

```
public function match(Zend_Controller_Request_Http $request)
{
    .....
    // set values only after all the checks are done
    $request->setModuleName($module);
    $request->setControllerName($controller);
    $request->setActionName($action);
    $request->setControllerModule($realModule);

    // set parameters from pathinfo
    for ($i = 3, $l = sizeof($p); $i < $l; $i += 2) {
        $request->setParam($p[$i], isset($p[$i+1]) ? urldecode($p[$i+1]) : '');
    }
    ....
}
```

In our case path info (`$p`) is `catalog/category/view/id/12`<sup>**3**</sup>. Due to this it will rewrite the param `id` and hence `$request` now becomes

```
Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Request_Http $request {
    $this->_params = array (
        'category' => 12
        'id'       => 12
    )
}
```

Due to this in `Mage_Catalog_ProductController::view()` action trighter `noRoute` action since it can't find a valid product id.

### Solution

Solution for this unique problem is pretty simple, change the `pathInfo` of the request before we throw exception in our observer. You can set path info like this.

```
$pathInfo = 'catalog/product/view/id' . $product->getId();
$request->setPathInfo($pathInfo);
```

---

<sup>1 : Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard</sup>

<sup>2 : Refers to `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard::match()`. This is the place where controller method is get triggered.</sup>

<sup>3 : `pathInfo` will not change when we do a fowrard. It will remain same.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
$e->prepareForward($actionName, $controllerName, $moduleName, $params);
```

try

```
$request->setModuleName($moduleName)
        ->setControllerName($controllerName)
        ->setActionName($actionName)
        ->setParam('id', $product->getId())
        ->setParam('category_id', $id);
```

Comment: this is what I tried first.. But it gives me lot of errors. `dispatch()` method in `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action` appears to trigger `_forward` action only when we have an exception of type `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Exception`. (I know the above code also do the same thing). Still the method above is not going to make any change if we didnt add `setDisptched(false)` to `$request`. Any way I am going to try this once more

Comment: I got 404 for the above code. Double checked it.

Comment: and I got that [**exception idea**](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9848/programmatically-301-redirect/10130#10130) from @Fabian :

Comment: I found the problem and put it as a solution. If you have time, please have a look at it :-)